# Can't download json schema using gradlew command

Tags: apollo, apollo-android

I can't figure out how to use the `gradlew` command to convert my `GraphQL` schema into a `JSON` file as it is [specified in the documentation](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/android/essentials/get-started/#downloading-a-schemajson-file).

I opened `CMD` in my project folder, ran the `gradlew` command once, and it gave me this error:

`Project 'module' not found in root project gradlew`

I created a module inside my project with the name "module" and now it's throwing the following error:

`Task 'downloadApolloSchema' not found in project ':module'.`

I've already added all the dependencies to the latest version (2.0.0 as of the time of posting) so I'm clueless as to why this is happening. I've already searched the web and found nothing about this...

This is the command I'm trying to issue in the `CMD`:

```
C:\Users\myuser\AndroidStudioProjects\GraphQLApp\app>..\gradlew :module:downloadApolloSchema -Pcom.apollographql.apollo.endpoint=https://graphql-udemy-android.herokuapp.com/graphql -Pcom.apollographql.apollo.schema=src/main/graphql/com/example/schema.json
```

I have to go up one directory (`..\`) since the `gradlew` command is in the above my app folder.

I'm on Windows, and my Gradle version is 6.4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry about that, the `module` part was mostly a placeholder for the gradle module where you apply the `com.apollographql.apollo` plugin. You can ignore it and gradle will find the appropriate task:

```
./gradlew downloadApolloSchema
```

This has been updated in the [project README](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-android/#downloading-a-schemajson-file) as well.

Answer (score 5):

You just change **./gradlew** to **.\gradlew**

1. Open the root terminal
2. Paste the code below and ENTER!

.\gradlew downloadApolloSchema --endpoint=https://**Your Endpoint**/graphql --schema=app/src/main/graphql/com/example/**Your Path**/schema.json

Have a good days!

Answer (score 0):

For windows i used

.\gradlew downloadApolloSchema --endpoint="https://rickandmortyapi.com/graphql" --schema=app/src/main/graphql/GetRepositories.json

**NOTICE** I used:
`.\` instead of `./`